# best way to substring with variable length

Tags: c#

I want to substring a variable length string with leading spaces to 25 or less characters. i got it to work but looking for other ways?

```
  ...  item.LineString.Trim().Substring(0, 
item.LineString.Trim().Length > 25 ? 25 : item.LineString.Trim().Length));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd use `Math.Min`:

```
var trimmed = item.LineString.Trim();
var substring = trimmed.Substring(0, Math.Min(25, trimmed.Length));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten it with:

```
item.LineString.Trim().Substring(0, Math.Min(25, item.LineString.Trim().Length));
```

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, LINQ's `Take` method does almost exactly what you're trying to accomplish with the `SubString` length logic.  While I'm confident its run-time efficiency isn't optimal, the following approach would also work:

```
string substring = new string(item.LineString.Trim().ToCharArray().Take(25).ToArray());
```

Just figured I'd put that out there, since the question was about "other ways" and not necessarily the "best way".

Answer (score 0):

To me the most obvious solution would be:

```
var maxLength = 25;
var lineString = item.LineString.Trim();
if (lineString.length > maxLength) { //to check the length and only substring if needed
  lineString = lineString.Substring(0, maxLength);
}
```

Actually it will compile to very similar code as this solution from the existing answers:

```
var maxLength = 25;
var lineString = item.LineString.Trim();
lineString = lineString.Substring(0, Math.Min(maxLength , lineString.Length));
```

So it's not really a matter of performance, but rather personal preference and (very important) readability! Because less lines of codes are not always a better solution :)